# Python colored text toggle issue

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to make a python script to loop text and toggle through it. I'm able to get python to toggle through the text once but what I cant get it to do is to keep toggling through the text. After it toggles through the text once I get a message that says

Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 24, in  hello() File "test.py", line 22, in hello hello() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import time, sys, os 
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

def hello():
    os.system('cls')
    init()

    hello = '''Hello!'''

    print(colored(hello,'green',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')

    print(colored(hello,'blue',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')

    print(colored(hello,'yellow',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    hello()

hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `hello` function with a string also called `hello` in the `hello` function. You could try to rename your `hello` string to `greeting` and using that instead.

Comment: Haha thank you I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the name `hello` for two different purposes, and they are conflicting.

You use it both for the function name and for a variable in the function. Change the name of one of them everywhere it is used and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you have both a variable and a function called `hello` so in the scope of the function `hello` is being overwritten. This can be fixed easily by renaming your string:

```
import time, sys, os
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

def hello():
    os.system('cls')
    init()

    greeting = '''Hello!'''

    print(colored(greeting,'green',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')

    print(colored(greeting,'blue',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')

    print(colored(greeting,'yellow',))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
    hello()

hello()
```